# NSPersisten[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have currently downloaded my Crashlogs for the current version of my iOS App. And I have seen a strange message which I cannot understand:

```
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSInternalMethods) _checkRequestForStore:withContext:originalRequest:andOptimisticLocking:]
```

**The exact stack**
[image]

What do you think about this log? I think it has something to do with saving a current changes in the store. 
Could you please help me improving my app.

Comment: Two different managed object contexts tried to change the same data. This is also known as an optimistic locking failure.  Try to set merge policy on your context. Your information is not sufficient to give any concrete answer. Could you post more about your stack setup and also crash log.

Comment: Sorry, I added the exact stack to this post but I have just a small log because it is a Crashlog from an user and I cannot reproduce this error. The solution with the merge policy sounds quite well because if I open the log in the project Xcode also marks the saving operation but there is also a try and catch. Now I added a merge policy and I will look if it maybe helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the **lightweight Migration** to your App
or

For temporary solution while development, you can delete your app from simulator or any device and run it again. Hope it will solve.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html)

Comment: Do you think the Core model is different to the current store? How can I see which entity is wrong?